# Execute with Ant works with absolute path but not relative path

Tags: java, ant, relative-path, absolute-path

I have the following snippet in my Ant script.  It executes just fine:

```
<exec executable="C:\test\foo\programName.exe" />
```

But then when I try to execute it by setting the directory, like so:

```
<exec executable="programName.exe"
  dir="C:\test\foo\" />
```

I get:

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Cannot run program "programName.exe"
>   (in directory "C:\test\foo"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system
>   cannot find the file specified

Please help!  Why is it not working when the directory is specified separately?

Comment: 'C:\test\foo' isn't a relative path. You may need to correct the question.

Comment: Edited.  In the end I need this to work with a relative path.  The fact that this doesn't work blows my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up sticking with this:

```
<exec executable="${basedir}\myexefile.exe}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the **resolveexecutable** attribute:

```
<exec executable="programName.exe" 
  resolveexecutable="true"
  dir="C:\test\foo\" />
```

> **resolveexecutable**     When this
>   attribute is true, the name of the
>   executable is resolved firstly against
>   the project basedir and if that does
>   not exist, against the execution
>   directory if specified. On Unix
>   systems, if you only want to allow
>   execution of commands in the user's
>   path, set this to false. since Ant 1.6
>     **No, default is false**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<property name="prog.dir" value="C:/test/foo" />
<exec executable="${prog.dir}/programName.exe"/>
```

It appears that the directory from which you execute the program must be in your build path.